# LitElement Component does not work properly on Angular

Tags: angular, web-component, lit-element, lit

I have downloaded a custom framework (based on LitElement), named as Astrouxds (https://www.astrouxds.com/) and i would like to use its rux-tabs component on Angular (I have already used some other its components, like rux-status etc.) but i could not make rux-tabs component work.

[image]

This the HTML that i used to show the tabs.

```
<main class="grid-zone grid-zone--main">
    <div class="grid-zone__content">
        <div class="grid-zone--main__subheader main__tabs">
            <div class="rux-form-field-div-search">
                <div class="rux-form-field search">
                    <input class="rux-form-field__text-input search" placeholder="Search …" type="search" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <rux-tabs compact id="mainTabs" transparent class="rux-tabs">
                <rux-tab class="secondary-toolbar__tabs__tab" id="t0" role="tab">Tab1</rux-tab>
                <rux-tab class="secondary-toolbar__tabs__tab" id="t1" role="tab">Tab2</rux-tab>
            </rux-tabs>
        </div>
        <rux-tab-panels aria-labeledby="mainTabs" class="grid-zone grid-zone--main__content">
            <rux-tab-panel aria-labeledby="t0" role="tabpanel">
                <div>Tab1 content</div>
            </rux-tab-panel>
            <rux-tab-panel aria-labeledby="t1" role="tabpanel">
                <div>Tab2 content</div>
            </rux-tab-panel>
        </rux-tab-panels>
    </div>
</main>
```

I also imported related .js into project

[image]

How can i use this component on Angular?

Comment: There is a big "contact support" orange button on their site

Comment: I already wrote to "contact support" but i have not received any response yet. thank you for your message.

Comment: If you don't get support in 48 hours ditch it

Comment: No one has answered yet (from their web site) :(

Comment: Then it is dead-and-no-future technology. So maybe voodoo can help... otherwise, ditch it